# delete a thread with all realated comments in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem on my website that really bugs me.. It's that I created a blog with laravel. In my blog you can create a thread and do comments under your or other users threads. After I did the comment functions, the 'delete thread' function didn't worked anymore. I searched so much for the mistake, until I decided to create a new database. This time I set all the foreign keys I need and something like : ON DELETE CASCADE. Before I couln't manually delete a thread because I've got a sql error message that sais I can't delete a thread because of foreign key reasons. With my new database, it worked again... but unfortunately I still can't delete a thread of me from my website... After I looked close into my error message, I've found a error message, that have a problem with my destroycomment method and my destroythread method.

So for a test I removed all the html that realates to comments, the comment functions and the comment route. And it worked! That means there is a problem with the 2 delete functions.

So please have a look over it, cause I nearly did everything I know.. So please help me!

```
 public function destroythread($id)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $thread->delete();
        return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@startpage', [Auth::user()->id]));
    }

 public function destroycomment($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $comment->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

In my HTML I'm using both functions! The destroycomment function works, but the destroythread doesn't. I think the reason is, because if the thread is gone, the comments would remain.

Edit: my last try after I gave up:

```
public function destroythread($id)
{
    $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
    $comment = Comment::query()->where('thread_id', $id)->get();
    $thread->delete();
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@startpage', [Auth::user()->id]));
}
```